# Obstructions to being a hyperplane section or a fibre of a Lefschetz pencil

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, singularity-theory

Given a smooth projective variety $X$, when could $X$ fail to be a hyperplane section in some other variety $Y$, or fail to be the fibre of some Lefschetz pencil $\widetilde{Y} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{1}$?

Here, the variety $Y$ is not fixed, but simply required to exist.

Answer (score 10):

A generic curve over $\mathbb{C}$ of large genus, say at least $24$, will not be a fibre of a Lefschetz pencil or even a hyperplane section.

The reason is that by the theorems of Harris-Mumford and Eisenbud-Harris, the moduli space of curves of large genus is of general type, so there can be no rational curve passing through a generic point. To use this one needs to know that all the smooth fibres of the pencil are not isomorphic. Since the local monodromy around a singular fibre is infinite by the Picard-Lefschetz formula, it suffices to show that there must be at least one singular fibre. But if all fibres are smooth, then $\tilde{Y}$ (the total space of the Lefschetz pencil) must be isomorphic to $C \times \mathbb{P}^1$. This cannot happen since  $C \times \mathbb{P}^1$ is not a blow up of any other surface.

Over a field of characteristic zero any very ample linear system contains a Lefschetz pencil, so it follows from the above that the smooth members of the linear system cannot all be isomorphic. But this would give rise to a unirational variety containing a generic point of the moduli space and this is not possible.

A similar argument should work for other classes of varieties whose moduli spaces are not uniruled.

Comment: Since OP did not specify that Y be smooth, this is technically false.  Every X is a hyperplane section of a projective cone over X.

Comment: Sandor -- I am afraid I do not understand the point you are trying to make.  The OP stated that X is smooth.  The projective cone over X is singular, but not along the generic hyperplane section X.  Rather it is singular at the vertex of the cone.  So I am afraid I do not understand your comment.

Comment: Jason, sorry. I had something else in mind. :(

Comment: Thanks. This is a very good answer. Perhaps I should have asked the converse: given a smooth projective variety $X$, when can and how can I hope to realize it as the fibre of a Lefschetz pencil?


Answer (score 4):

Your question is related to the problem of the existence of non-trivial extensions of subvarieties $X \subset \mathbb P^N$ to $\mathbb P^{N+1}$. An extension of $X$ is just a subvariety $Y$ of $\mathbb P^{N+1}$  such that $X= Y \cap \mathbb P^{N}$. It is called trivial if $Y$ is the join of $X$ and a point outside of $\mathbb P^N$.

This is a classical question that was studied by the Italian school of algebraic geometry. For instance, Scorza proved that the Veronese surface in $\mathbb P^5$ does not admit non-trivial extensions.

More recently, the problem has been studied by Zak, S. L'vovsky, L. Badescu, among many others. In [Extensions of projective varieties and deformations](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-39/issue-1/Extensions-of-projective-varieties-and-deformations-I/10.1307/mmj/1029004452.full) by S. L'vovsky you will find the following result:

**Theorem.** Suppose $X$ is not $\mathbb P^N$ nor a quadric. If $\dim X \ge 2$ and $H^1(X,TX\otimes \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^N}(-1))=0$ then every extension of $X$ is trivial.

For a very nice introduction to this circle of ideas see the first chapter of the book
[Projective geometry and formal geometry](https://books.google.com/books/about/Projective_geometry_and_formal_geometry.html?id=WtsHOfktVBsC) by L. Badescu. Unfortunately, the relevant Chapter doesn't seem to be available from Google books.

Of course this  does not answer your question as the embedding of $X$ into $\mathbb P^N$ is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

May be the paper "On manifolds that cannot be ample divisors" by Sommese (Math. Annalen 1976) is relevant.

Among other things he proves that an Abelian variety of dimension >1 is not an ample divisor.